# VPS With 30 Sites - How much RAM do I need?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, memory, vps

I have a VPS running a 64-Bit Windows 2008 server with: 1.9 GB of Ram [that RAM is dedicated to this VPS - not shared]
Currently I have 30 websites (all running the my custom ecommerce app) running on this VPS.
However if access 10-20 sites at the same time the server will max out and I will see various out of memory errors.
Should I set a memory limit for each site in the site's app pool?
Like Max memory available?

I wondering why I'm suffering this performance issue. Last month I had about 50  (all running the my custom ecommerce app) with a shared hosting company. This was one of those hosts that allowed unlimited sites. I never had a memory issue and I'm sure my VPS has more resources available than a shared box with hundreds of other sites.

This is my vps company:
http://kickassvps.com/services/windows_vps/plans.php

I would like to go the dedicated server route, however I cannot afford more than $70 a month right now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: duplicate of capacity planning which is offtopic

Answer (score 2):

> I'm sure my VPS has more resources
>   available than a shared box with
>   hundreds of other sites.

Don't be so sure. VPSes are also shared on that same physical machine with others. The amount of RAM may not be dedicated and if the other VPSes on the same server are also busy - with CPU, RAM or Disk Throughput, then your VPS may be suffering. The shared server may have had a lot more ram, and other other sites may not be as busy as your sites.

With 30 sites, and a custom E-Commerce app, it is hard to say how much RAM you are going to need because it varies greatly with how busy the sites are, how large the databases are, etc. Have you done analysis on your VPS to see what is using the RAM and where it can be optimized?

You can set max memory for your sites but if you get a busier site it will absolutely limit how much traffic it will be able to handle. I don't want to question your business model, but it seems with 30 e-commerce sites you should be able to buy a dedicated server to properly support those sites.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using swap space for the peak load times? Using swap will allow continued processing but at a slower speed. If your previous provider allowed this configuration to work reasonably, I suspect that your shared server had more swap space than currently configured. I may be wrong, but it's a simple place to start looking for a "quick" fix.

I wouldn't normally run a Win2k8 server with only 2G of RAM (4G would be my personal minimum, but it highly depends on your workload) but if I did, I would have at least 2G of swap, potentially 4G, but more than that may incur significant performance penalties if it's regularly using a lot more than the 2G of physical RAM.

Comment: i believe the issue from for now 13 years should be solved already...